# Why is my role check gone after I added a paging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

I have some parts of my view dependent on if a user is authenticated and their role.  For example:

```
@*@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Class>*@
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Project.Models.Class>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("canEdit"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

    </div>
}
```

But after adding in paging, suddenly I've lost this ability and I can no longer see my authenticated links?

Comment: Put a debug point on `@if(..`. Then observe the value of `Request.IsAuthenticated` and `User.IsInRole`.

Comment: Thanks Khalid.  I'd tried that, but it's not hitting the point for some reason.  Very strange.  Just jumping over it and displaying the page without it.

Comment: can you hover over the variables and see the values? Then at least you know which one of the 2 is causing the if clause to fail.

Comment: Thanks counter.  It was a very strange issue where I couldn't debug at all.  After a couple of hours, it started working again.  I did rearrange where I had the link, but it's still confusing to me.  I had even checked to see if it was somehow hidden behind the menu or another div.  Thanks for the help though, but still not sure if it was just something fluky or a real issue.